# Coordinator node timed out on Cassandra cqlsh shell

Tags: cassandra

I am new to cassandra and trying to do multi node setup on two Mac machine. Its not a datastax casandra.
like my Ip is 10.100.1.12 and other machine ip is 10.100.1.15. I have changed the following properties in cassandra.yaml files on bothe the machine:

**`10.100.1.15:`**

- seeds: "127.0.0.1,10.100.1.12,10.100.1.15"
- listen_address: 10.100.1.15
- rpc_address: 10.100.1.15
- endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch

**`10.100.1.12:`**

- seeds: "127.0.0.1,10.100.1.12,10.100.1.15"
- listen_address: 10.100.1.12
- rpc_address: 10.100.1.12
- endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch

  cassandra runs fine cqlsh is also opening using the command
  bin/cqlsh 10.100.1.12

but when i am trying to retrieve the count of tables its showing me the error:

**ReadTimeout: Error from server: code=1200 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0 responses." info={'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}**

i tried changing the read_request_timeout_in_ms proprtty from 5000 to 20000 but still i am getting the same error. Could anyone please help what i am doing wrong?

the table schema is following:

```
cqlsh:app_auditor> describe table traffic_data;

CREATE TABLE app_auditor.traffic_data (
    current_time bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    appid bigint,
    attributes map<text, text>,
    device bigint,
    flow_type text,
    message_time bigint
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 86400
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

the count query i am using is
select count(*) from traffic_data;

Comment: You definitely don't want 127.0.0.1 in your list of seeds. Just the 2 listen addresses. What is the result of nodetool ring when you have both nodes up and running?

Comment: Can you execute Normal queries  ?

Comment: i can execute describe queries, like describe keyspaces and tables. the nodetool status is following:Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address      Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.100.1.12  472.14 KiB  256          ?       2c09d826-387a-49d6-a99a-c538fcb159cb  rack1
UN  10.100.1.15  887.97 KiB  256          ?       b945b293-2f54-4440-afa0-d0536bed3230  rack1

Comment: show your table schema and the query. I think it's because of your count query

Answer (score 3):

**In Cassandra count(*) is very costly, cassandra needs to scan all the row from all the node just to give you the count, that's why it's giving you timeout exception.**

Instead of using count(*) maintain a counter table, like the below one :

```
CREATE TABLE traffic_counter (
    type int PRIMARY KEY,
    traffic_count counter
);
```

When a data insert into traffic_data data, increment the value of traffic_count

```
UPDATE traffic_counter SET traffic_count = traffic_count + 1 WHERE type = 0;
```

Now you can select traffic count very efficiently.

```
SELECT traffic_count FROM traffic_counter WHERE type = 0;
```

Comment: I am getting the same error in  create statement as well. even if i do select * from table traffic_data limit 1;, its showing the same error. I am displaying only one record.

Comment: Is attributes have huge amount of data ?

Comment: right now the table is empty. It should fetch 0 count.

Comment: Remove 127.0.0.1 from your seeds, and restart Cassandra

Comment: i had done that also .But i guess its giving problem for the tables i have to use for my project. for other dummy and test tables its working fine.Not sure whats the problem is